# html tag ID referenced in java code in JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp, tags

Is there a way to refer the id of an html tag in java code in a jsp, e.g.:

```
...
<body>
    <h1>Order state</h1>

    <p id="name">Customer name: ${p.customerName}</p><br />

...

<%

        request.setAttribute("customerName", <object>);
%>
...
```

So in this example I want to refer to paragraph's value ${p.customerName} in java code in place of < object>

Answer (score 0):

Since ${p.customerName} is a JSTL variable , by default its set in page scope. So you can use :

```
request.setAttribute("customerName", pageContext.getAttribute("customerName"));
```

Comment: thanks for the advice. it is not in jstl. i debugged it and unfortunately it didnt pick up the value of that html tag